# ¿Cómo generar números decimales aleatorios en Java dentro de rango?

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de generar números aleatorios en Java dentro de un rango determinado con el siguiente código:

```
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Pero esto sólo me genera números en el conjunto de los números enteros. ¿Cómo puedo obtener números que también sean decimales?

Comment: Hector, dejo en mi respuesta un método que será útil para ti!.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`rand` debería tener un método `nextDouble`. Este método no acepta argumentos ya que genera un número entre 0.0 y 1.0 Para ajustar ese número a tu rango puedes usar un código similar a este:

```
double randomNum = min + ( max - min ) * rand.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 6):

Este es un método muy útil, muy importante el uso de `nextDouble()`

```
public static double getRandom(Double valorMinimo, Double valorMaximo) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return  valorMinimo + ( valorMaximo - valorMinimo ) * rand.nextDouble();
    }
```

> **nextDouble()**  método que es usado para obtener el siguiente pseudoaleatorio, valor distribuido uniformemente entre 0.0 y 1.0 de la
>   secuencia de este número del generador aleatorio.

Como un ejemplo:

Usando el método anteriormente descrito, escribe 100 numeros aleatorios entre los valores 1.1 y 2.5:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(getRandom(1.1, 2.5)));
```

**[ver demo aquí!](http://ideone.com/mU05Xg)**

Comment: Si vas a usar un objeto de la clase `Random`, no estaría de más que lo añadieras como parámetro.  Si no, mejor usa `Math.random()`.
Tampoco es mala idea usar `double` y no `Double` para evitar conversiones extra de objeto a primitivo y viceversa.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías usar esto

```
(Math.random()*20)+1;
```

Lo que crearía un aleatorio entre 1 y 19 con decimales.

```
19 = 20 - 1 // Max - Min
```

Comment: No funciona, hice una prueba `(Math.random()*10)+5 = 14.98...` Genera números sobre el máximo.

Comment: *10 + 5, deberia generar números entre 5 y 15, 14.98 esta en el rango

Answer (score 3):

Puedes generar un random en el que el valor minimo sea (`min + 100`) y luego dividir el numero obtenido por `100.0`. De este modo que obtendrías un número con dos decimales:

```
double randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min + 100 / 100.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [este código](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724404/random-floating-point-double-in-inclusive-range), sólo ten cuidado que este código jamás te dará el valor de `max`:

```
function randomInRange(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max-min) + min;
}
```

Usa la clase [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), aunque seguramente también podrías usar la función `nextDouble` de la clase [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
Random r = new Random();

double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Poner exclusivamente código no permite que los demás valoren tu solución. ¿Podrías explicar un poco más qué es lo que se hace y por qué es aceptable tu enfoque? Gracias.